# How to get textContent from ReactElement?

Tags: reactjs

Given a `ReactElement` like this:

```
var myReactElement = (
  <span><strong>Chel</strong>tenham VIC 3192</span>
);
```

How could I get its text content (`"Cheltenham VIC 3192"` in this case)?

**Context:**

Imagine an autosuggest component. User can specify how to render the suggestions. For example, user can provide the following function to the component:

```
function(suggestion) {
  return (
    <span><strong>{suggestion[0]}</strong>{suggestion.slice(1)}</span>
  );
}
```

When suggestion is selected, I need to set the value of the input field to the text content of the suggestion, so if "**M**entone" was rendered in the suggestion list, the value of the input field should be "Mentone".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do? There is a `componentDidMount` method where the DOM was realized and you could use `innerText`. But, since that's just JSX syntax that was created, why wouldn't you just extract it in the `render`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I added the context to the question to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a working example, something like below should work. In this case, I've added code to wire up the `onClick` for the `div` element wrapping each item. And using `bind`, included the suggestion that was rendered, so that when the `onSuggestionClick` event callback is executed, it has the full text available (along with any other details you might have in each `suggestion`).

This assumes that the `suggestions` are in an array in this case. You could also just use an index if needed. You might find that you'll need to add a `key` attribute to the outermost `div` for each item so that React properly tracks changes to the suggestion list (so that the virtual DOM can be properly "diffed").

```
function suggestionFunction(suggestion) {
  return (
    <span><strong>{suggestion[0]}</strong>{suggestion.slice(1)}</span>
  );
}


var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    onSuggestionClick:function(suggestion) {
        this.setState({
            current: suggestion
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var suggestions = this.props.suggestions || [];
        return (<div>
            <div>
                <input value={ this.state.current } />
            </div>
            { suggestions.map(function(suggestion) {
                return (<div onClick=_this.onSuggestionClick(_this, suggestion)>
                    { suggestionFunction(suggestion) }
                </div>);
            })}
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to pass the index up when something changes.  This allows the parent to update its state, and then everything's updated.

Pulling data out of the dom make sense in other libraries, but React empowers us to rarely do this.  Choose your source of truth wisely :-)

```js
var C = React.createClass({
  handleSelect(index){
    this.props.onSelect(index);
  },
  render(){
    var options = this.props.options
      // map, but keep track of the index
      .map((x, i) => [x, i])
      // some filtering thing
      // this also allows efficient inserts and removals by giving a good key
      .filter(([x, i]) => x[0] === 'b');
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <ul role="listbox">
          {options.map(([x, i]) =>
             <li key={i} onClick={e => this.handleSelect(i)}>
                 {this.props.renderItem(x, i)}
             </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ITEMS = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "bananas"];
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {selected: "baz"};
  },
  handleSelect(index){
    // setState based on the index
    // note that even though bananas is only the 3rd item rendered
    // in the dom, index here will be 4 so this works
    this.setState({selected: this.props.items[index]});
  },
  render(){
    var renderItem = x => { 
      var cn = x === this.state.selected ? 'active' : null;
      return <strong className={cn}>{x}</strong>
    };
    return <div>
      Hello, world!
      <C options={this.props.items} 
         renderItem={renderItem} 
         onSelect={this.handleSelect} value={this.state.selected} />
    </div>;
  }
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dodajayaya/2/edit?js,output)

Answer (score -2):

You can pass text as props to component and render props in JSX. This is the right way.